# Canadian Online Visitor Visa Application NO application number showing

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas, applications, application-status

I have applied for a visitor visa online, uploaded the ridiculous amounts of documents required, carefully scrutinized each and everyone of them and I can confirm my visa appllication is 100% correct / complete to the last letter.

### NO APPLICATION NUMBER IN CIC Online Dashboard

So after uploading my docs I paid the $100 via credit card and the transaction went through instantly, with me receiving a confirmation email at the same time. (Quick to take money slow to respond to queries...)

Email was an automated standardized email reading as follow:

[image]

**MY PROBLEM / CONCERN / WORRY**

When I logon to the online visa application tracker, on the CIC website (Canada Imigration And Citizenship)

My dashboard looks as follows for my submitted online application .

[image]

***Notice how there is NO application number showing...? Is this normal?***

I would have thought that just like the automated payment email generated an auto payment receipt number, so to would an application number automatically get assigned to your application (as the primary key) *you know so you can provide this for inquiries and what not.*

**QUESTIONS**

- Has anyone ever experienced something similar, or gone through the
  online application process? If yes can you be so kind to provide me
  with some info?
- Is it normal NOT to have an application number after 4-days?
- I have submitted the online application last Friday, 18 Aug 17. Does anyone know if weekends count towards "the number of application / processing days?" Currently the estimated processing time is 24-days for visitor visa from my country?
- **Should I be worried** and try to intervene by **cancelling** and re-applying or something similar?

Any Tips much appreciated! A DESPERATE PLEA FOR HELP!

**Additional Info**

My nationality is South African thus I require no bio-metrics or health reports.

Comment: Its a shame that such a properly written question is nothing more than the post submission anxiety :)

Comment: @HankyPanky so are you insinuating that I dont need to worry about this? It is just weird, I have read some horror stories online!

Comment: Yes, you don't. I don't know the decision but I do know that the process is on even if you can't find a serial number and it's too early to panic. Give it the due time they ve mentioned. They are clearly saying you do not need to login to check for any updates etc so just wait it out

Comment: @HankyPanky Thanks for calming my nerves. Everything in my application is pretty straight forward so cant see any problems from document side. However my main concern is the visa issue date since my flight departs  21 September and I dont have an option for a date change :-(  Quick question `I have read on their website that if you havent received a serial nr / application nr after 5 days you should contact them...However, I dont want to file case unnecessarily. Would you say (best guess) weekends counts towards the 5-days or would you say (guess) its 5-business days`, not stated on website

Comment: 5 Days would almost always mean 5 working days. So mail them on the next friday or the monday after

Comment: Thanks @HankyPanky much appreciated. Out of curiosity have you ever been to Canada?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about post-submission anxiety, rather than a real problem.